# Add more emails to facebook app developer console to get Alert

Tags: facebook

Any one please guide us to add more emails to facebook app developer console. We are multiple developer working and we want that all of us to get an email if any alert being send from facebook not just to primary email.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any admin of the application can set up to receive email notifications when there are notifications from the application.

You can edit the settings in developer settings:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/
```